# Get username in web app in Dynamics 2011 (in C#)

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to get the username of the current user in a web app that's running inside `MS Dynamics 2011`.

If I used **Environment.UserName** it returns the username of the **AppPool** the app is running under. How do I determine the actual user who is logged in to **Dynamics**?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a website that is using windows authentication, this is how you can lookup the username of the request:

```
var name = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

You can then use that name to lookup the SystemUserId of the user and do impersonation if need be.

Answer (score -1):

```
Guid userGuid;

if(Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated == true)

{

WhoAmIRequest userRequest = new Microsoft.Crm.SdkTypeProxy.WhoAmIRequest();

WhoAmIResponse user = (Microsoft.Crm.SdkTypeProxy.WhoAmIResponse)objCrmService.Execute(userRequest);

userGuid = user.UserId;

}

else //ifd

{

  userGuid = new Guid(Context.User.Identity.Name);

}
```

//Populating a dropdown with all users and selecting the current user

```
SelectUser(userGuid);
private void SelectUser(Guid userId)
{    
 BusinessEntityCollection users = LoadUsers();//Load all users
    for (int i = 0; i < users.BusinessEntities.Count; i++)
    {
        DynamicEntity entity = (DynamicEntity)users.BusinessEntities[i];
        if (entity.Properties.Contains(“systemuserid”) && ((Key)entity.Properties["systemuserid"]).Value == userId)
        {
            DDLUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem(entity.Properties["fullname"].ToString(), ((Key)entity.Properties["systemuserid"]).Value.ToString()));
            DDLUsers.Items[i].Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            DDLUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem(entity.Properties["fullname"].ToString(), ((Key)entity.Properties["systemuserid"]).Value.ToString()));

        }

    }

  }
```